# Navigation Architecture Component - search using SearchView

Tags: searchview, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

i researched many posts and articles around this, but could not get a good answer.

i am running into issues while implementing search using Navigation Architecture component.
i have a MainActivity, mainFragment and a searchFragment. mainFragment is set as destination in my navigationGraph. i have these doubts 
1. Search should be made part of activity  or mainFragment  what is the right approach.
2. If search is made part of Activity then handling the up button for my search becomes an issue. the up button on search exits the MainActivity, does not land in mainFragment. I was thinking that NavController should have stack containing mainFragment and then searchFragment, once you press up button in searchFragment, it should popout and mainFragment should display. Looks like i am missing something.